# Олень: как имя перекочевало в название животного?

Tags: этимология

Насколько я знаю, слово "олень" изначально было именем собственным. Но как получилось, что оно перестало быть именем и  перекочевало в название животного?

Answer (score 6):

А откуда у Вас сведения об изначальном имени собственном?

В значении "жвачное парнокопытное млекопитающее животное, со стройным сложением, с тонкими ногами и коротким хвостом, с ветвистыми рогами (у самок отсутствующими у большинства видов") (толкование Cervus), в древнерусском языке отмечено в XII веке. Индоевропейский корень : *el-, *ol-; индоевропейская основа: *el-en- (*ol-en-).

[ОЛЕНЬ | slovopedia.com](http://www.slovopedia.com/22/206/1638527.html)

Позднее в греческом языке слово с этой основой означало "молодой олень" (см. у Гомера). В разных языках ещё позднее от этой основы были образованы слова со значением "самка оленя" (elne; alne - литовский), "лань" (elain - валлийский (кимрский)), "лось" (alnis - латышский), "зверь" (alne - древнепрусский).Черных П.Я. Историко-этимологический словарь современного русского языка: В 2 т. - 5-е изд., стереотип. - М.: Рус. яз., 2002. Т. 1: А - Пантомима. - 624 с. С. 596. С. 466 ("лань"), 492 ("лось").

Если Вы имеете в виду  "Оленка",то,видимо, оно как раз от ранее указанного индоевропейского корня, и имело значение "маленький оленёнок, оленуха"

Answer (score 1):

Имена собственные типа "Елена" по одной из версий, скорее всего - ничего общего с действительностью не имеющей, могли быть производными от Олень (Елень), но никак не наоборот. 
Остальное - у Людмилы.